# While executing below code it is not printing the title and url in the output console and no error is displayed

Tags: output

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\API\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

While executing below code it is not printing the title and url in the output console and  no error is displayed.